# Adding multiple items in a list to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, calculator, python-3.9

I've been writing a calculator and a problem that faced me is that I can't add more than two numbers at a time.

I decided that since I'm using split then adding the items in the list should be the best solution.

It does read the number in index 0 as an int indeed, but it doesn't for the rest.

I tried to loop over the items in the list in order to add them.

That failed so I tried to use the `sum()` function in order to sum the items in the new list and then add that to the number in index 0, but still it doesn't work.

My code:

```
def calc(x):
        if '+' in x:
            i = x.split('+')
            a = sum(i[1:])
            print(int(i[0]) + int(a))
```

The error that pops up here is:

```
line 5, in calc
    a = sum(i[1:])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: The variable *i* will be a (potentially empty) list of strings. So you're trying to sum strings

Answer (score 0):

Splitting a string yields a list of strings. You can't `sum` strings.

But you can turn your list of strings into ints and sum it.

```
>>> [int(x) for x in '1 + 2 + 3 + 4'.split('+')]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> sum(int(x) for x in '1 + 2 + 3 + 4'.split('+'))
10
```

Which might also be expressed with a loop. In this case, performing multiplication.

```
>>> result = 1
>>> for x in "1 * 2 * 3 * 4".split('*'):
...   result *= int(x)
...
>>> result
24
```

Comment: OK that worked, thanks, but what if i wanna do a different operation, i don't think the same way will work, my problem was that i wanna loop through the list and get the sum of each item in there, because if that worked i can do the same to other operations like subtraction, multiplication or division

Answer (score 0):

The variable i will be a (potentially empty) list of strings. So you're trying to sum strings.

Assuming your function is only meant to handle addition of integers then:

```
def calc(s):
    return sum(map(int, s.split('+')))

print(calc('19+17'))
```

**Output:**

```
36
```

**Additional:**

Let's extend this function to support addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. No error/sanity checking so exceptions may arise if the string format is not exactly as expected. Only supports a single X/Y pair. An expression such as '1+2+3' will not work

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv
import re

opmap = {'+': add, '-': sub, '*': mul, '/': truediv}

def calc(s):
    x, o, y = re.search(r'(\d+)\s*([+-/*])\s*(\d+)', s).groups()
    return opmap[o](int(x), int(y))
        
print(calc('19 * 17'))
```

**Output:**

```
323
```

**And finally:**

Providing you trust the source of the string to be evaluated then you could just use the built-in *eval()* function

Comment: What lib is that?

Comment: @Rookie-kinda Not sure what you mean by "lib". This answer uses 2 standard modules:- *operator* and *re* both of which are available by default as part of your Python installation

Comment: i meant library , or module

Comment: well, i never used those modules but i will look into them, this way is waay more convenient than what i was trying to do tbh.